# NumPy types with underscore: `int_`, `float_`, etc

Tags: python, numpy, naming-conventions

What is the significance of the underscore suffixing in `int_`, `float_`, etc.?

Comment: I would suppose it's so they don't clash with builtins.  It's the same reason you wouldn't create your own class named `list`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From page 21 of [Guide to Numpy](http://www.tramy.us/numpybook.pdf) by TE Oliphant:

> Names for the data types that would
>   clash with standard Python object
>   names are followed by a trailing
>   underscore, ’ ’. These data types are
>   so named because they use the same
>   underlying precision as the
>   corresponding Python data types.

. . .

> The array types `bool_`, `int_`, `complex_`,
>   `float_`, `object_`, `unicode_`, and `str_`
>   are enhanced-scalars. They are very
>   similar to the standard Python types
>   (without the trailing underscore) and
>   inherit from them (except for `bool_` and
>   `object_`). They can be used in place of
>   the standard Python types whenever
>   desired. Whenever a data type is
>   required, as an argument, the standard
>   Python types are recognized as well.

Comment: Oliphant's book looks great. Thanks for posting it.

Answer (score 5):

If you're unsure if your variable is scalar, list, or array, using the ones with "_" will ensure your code will work regardless (if that's the behavior you intended). See the example code below.

As of `numpy` version 1.20.0, `np.float64` or `np.float32` works on scalars and lists.

```
import numpy as np  # numpy >= 1.20.0
scalar = 3
L1 = [3]
L2 = [1, 2, 3]

np.float64(scalar)  # okay
np.float64(L1)  # okay
np.float64(L2)  # okay

np.float_(scalar)  # okay
np.float_(L1)  # okay
np.float_(L2)  # okay
```

Note that `np.float_` is just an [alias](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.float_) of `np.double`.

Comment: How does this change [now that `np.float` is deprecated](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.20.0-notes.html#using-the-aliases-of-builtin-types-like-np-int-is-deprecated)?

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect the changes. `np.float` is deprecated but `np.float_` isn't, though the latter is just an alias of `np.double`