# What is the difference between the types <type 'numpy.string_'> and <type 'str'>?

Tags: python, string, numpy, types

Is there a difference between the types `<type 'numpy.string_'>` and `<type 'str'>`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`numpy.string_` is the NumPy datatype used for arrays containing fixed-width byte strings. On the other hand, `str` is a native Python type and can not be used as a datatype for NumPy arrays*.

If you create a NumPy array containing strings, the array will use the `numpy.string_` type (or the `numpy.unicode_` type in Python 3). More precisely, the array will use a sub-datatype of `np.string_`:

```
>>> a = np.array(['abc', 'xy'])
>>> a
array(['abc', 'xy'], dtype='<S3')
>>> np.issubdtype('<S3', np.string_)
True
```

In this case the datatype is `'<S3'`: the `<` denotes the byte-order (little-endian), `S` denotes the string type and `3` indicates that each value in the array holds up to three characters (or bytes).

One property that `np.string_` and `str` share is immutability. Trying to increase the length of a Python `str` object will create a new object in memory. Similarly, if you want fixed-width NumPy array to hold more characters, a new larger array will have to be created in memory.

---

* Note that it is possible to create a NumPy `object` array which contains *references* to Python `str` objects, but such arrays behave quite differently to normal arrays.

Comment: I think `str` can be used in numpy arrays. I just have an error because of that. One array returns `type(X[0])` `str` the other array returns `numpy.str_`.

Comment: Wonder why numpy uses np.string_ instead of np.string? Why '_' in the end?

Comment: @HelinWang check out the following question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205020/numpy-types-with-underscore-int-float-etc

Comment: You can find the whole inheritance hierarchy in the following link:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html