# Why full function in NumPy can't take dtype=str

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, numpy, dtype

Why i see just one letter instead of "cube"
When i didn't type dtype="str" it worked.
My question is why?

code:

```
np.full((3,3,3),"cube",dtype=str)
```

results:

```
array([[['c', 'c', 'c'],
        ['c', 'c', 'c'],
        ['c', 'c', 'c']],

       [['c', 'c', 'c'],
        ['c', 'c', 'c'],
        ['c', 'c', 'c']],

       [['c', 'c', 'c'],
        ['c', 'c', 'c'],
        ['c', 'c', 'c']]], dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: Some answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086936/what-is-the-difference-between-the-types-type-numpy-string-and-type-str)

Comment: You can set dtype to the largest string you expect for your array. If that would be a string of, for example, length 34, use dtype='<U34`. That will take a potential large amount of reserved memory, that's a tradeoff to make. Otherwise, you can also use dtype=object for a more generic item (size) stored in each array element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
np.full((3,3,3),"cube",dtype=str)
```

**is equivalent to**

```
np.full((3,3,3),"cube",dtype='U1')
```

It will just take the first element of the string.

---

You can get full result by:

```
np.full((3,3,3),"cube",dtype=object)
```

or

```
np.full((3,3,3),"cube",dtype='U4')  # U4 as you have 4 letters in cube, you can do any U>4 like U5, U6, etc.
```

or just remove `dtype=str`. Upon removing it will take the complete length of the string.

```
np.full((3,3,3),"cube")
```

Answer (score 1):

Dude, just remove ( dtype : it's optional ).

Code :

```
np.full( (3,3,3), "cube" )
```

Syntax :

```
numpy.full(shape, fill_value, dtype=None, order='C')
```

Answer (score 1):

Part of the source code for `full` is (see the [source] link in docs):

```
 if dtype is None:
        fill_value = asarray(fill_value)
        dtype = fill_value.dtype
    a = empty(shape, dtype, order)
    multiarray.copyto(a, fill_value, casting='unsafe')
```

`np.asarray` can deduce a 'U4' dtype for the fill value of 'cube'.

But `np.empty(shape, 'str')` produces a 'U1' dtype.  It has no information about `fill_value`.

So that's why, without your dtype, it deduces that it needs a large enough string to hold 4 characters, but without it, it just allocates space for 1 character.

Answer (score 0):

That should work

```
import numpy as np
np.full((3,3,3),"cube",dtype='U4')
```