# Why do I have to use np.string_? Why can't I use np.string without the underscore?

Tags: python, numpy

I just started learning NumPy, so I'm still a bit dazed with all of its ins and outs. I'm learning how to create arrays with specific data types. I'm a bit confused with this:

When I create an array of int32 data type, it shows just that:

```
a = np.zeros((2, 3), dtype=np.int32)
print(a)
print(a.dtype)
```

The print statement shows: `int32`

When I create an array of float data type, it shows just that:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=np.float)
print(a)
print(a.dtype)
```

The print statement shows: `float64`

However, when I create an array of data type string, it doesn't have a similar output:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6], dtype=np.string_)

print(a)
print(a.dtype)
```

The print statement shows:

```
[b'1' b'2' b'3' b'4' b'5' b'6']
|S1
```

Why? What does it mean? Also, why can't I choose `dtype=np.string`? Why do I need the underscore `dtype=np.string_`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between the types <type 'numpy.string\_'> and <type 'str'>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086936/what-is-the-difference-between-the-types-type-numpy-string-and-type-str)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/6205237/982257  I think the reason for the underscores are twofold: Some people will tend to do (against recommendation) `from numpy import *`, and these underscored names will at least prevent them from overriding basic Python built-ins (albeit not all...).  Otherwise, in code editors and stuff it will also prevent them from being syntax-highlighted the same as said built-ins in some cases...

Comment: @Iguananaut It doesn't answer. I wanted to know why I get an error if I use np.string. It looks like I need the underscore np.string_

Comment: Simply because `np.string` is not defined.  There's nothing special syntactically about the _, it's just a naming decision that's followed consistently for other dtypes. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/6103  For the same results you can also use `np.array(..., dtype=bytes)` or if you want normal unicode strings, `np.array(..., dtype=str)`.  You don't have to use the Numpy aliases.

Comment: `np.string_` is documented here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html?highlight=string_#other-aliases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, if you simply do:

```
>>> np.string_
<class 'numpy.bytes_'>
>>>
```

It automatically gives a `numpy.bytes_` object for each value.'

So you should do `np.str_` as follows:

```
>>> np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6], dtype=np.str_)
array(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'], dtype='<U1')
>>>
```

Which gives a regular numpy scalar string dtype, which is the same as regular `str`.

Using just `str` would be easier:

```
>>> np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6], dtype=str)
array(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'], dtype='<U1')
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So it looks like I can use str, str_, and string_, but not string. I get an error if I do. 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Desktop/1.py", line 134, in <module>
    g = np.array([1,2,3,4], dtype=np.string)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 214, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute "
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'string'

Comment: @SpamMeUpScottie Numpy does not have the attribute of `string` unfortunately...,

Comment: Totally, just did but cannot upvote. I need at least 15 rep.

Comment: That `AttributeError` tells you why.  Projecting from patterns is not as reliable as reading the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

*What does it mean?*

Simply speaking `S1` is length-1 string, consider following example

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array(['A','A','A'],dtype=np.string_)
arr3 = np.array(['ABC','ABC','ABC'],dtype=np.string_)
arr5 = np.array(['ABCDE','ABCDE','ABCDE'],dtype=np.string_)
print(arr1.dtype)  # |S1
print(arr3.dtype)  # |S3
print(arr5.dtype)  # |S5
```

Note analogy with another `numpy` datatypes - if you know you have certain number of say length-5 strings, you can easily compute memory required as in case of say `uint8` or `int32` and as opposed to variable length strings.

Comment: Thank you! That makes total sense. 
Now, two questions if I may. The array output has a b next to each element. Why?
Also, if I use np.str instead, it prints <U1 for data type. What does it mean? 
I want to upvote your answer, but I need at least 15 rep. If you upvote my question, I'll do it for you.